# How to send api request with authentication in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest-client, airborne

I have this curl command to send api request with authentication. I am writing a test using airborne where I need to send an api request inside the test. 
curl command

```
curl https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json \
  -v -u test@email.com:Abcd1234
```

I have the test like below but I need to add the authentication. How do i do it?

```
describe 'Test to GET' do
  it 'should get the existing data'do
  get "https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json","test@email.com":"Abcd1234"
  expect_status(200)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-u` option sends a basic auth header to the client.

The very top of [`README`](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne#making-requests) of *Airborne* shows how to send an auth header:

```
describe 'Test to GET' do
  it 'should get the existing data' do
    get "https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json",
        { 'x-auth-token' => 'my_token' }
    expect_status(200)
  end
end
```

How to get the token out of `user`:`password` pair I’d leave for you as a homework (e. g. you might simply log `curl` request.)

You also might set the auth header globally via [*Airborne* config](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne#configuration).